# Why is my token (cookie) not being set in the browser (using JWT in MERN stack app)?

Tags: node.js, express, cookies, jwt

I am sending a cookie when authorizing a login but it does not appear when looking at the cookies stored in the browser. The code that sends the cookie is the following:

```
app.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
    const { email, password } = req.body;
    
    const user = await User.findOne({email})
    if (!user) {
        return res.status(404).json({message: 'User not found'});
    }
    if (!bcrypt.compareSync(password, user.password)) {
        return res.status(401).json({message: 'Incorrect password'});
    }
    jwt.sign({email:user.email, id:user._id}, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {}, (err, token) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(500).json(err);
        }
        res.cookie('token', token).json(user);
    });
    

});
```

And the http response looks like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Express
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:5173
Vary: Origin
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Set-Cookie: token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJlbWFpbCI6Im1hcmNvcy5zZWNvLmFuZGVyc29uQGdtYWlsLmNvbSIsImlkIjoiNjUyYmUxODk4NGE4MjE2MWM3NWY1MTcwIiwiaWF0IjoxNjk3NDY2NTU1fQ.TbzDhQgQydtppUBo4NfMWmYhtJpZWUxrvWRv4Dqqmas; Path=/
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 175
ETag: W/"af-QCiPuvEnfeYRFPIjeqReewm0cLM"
Date: Mon, 16 Oct 2023 14:29:15 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=5
```

The cookie is in the response but it is not being stored does anyone know why?
My backend is in port 4000 and frontend in 5173 just in case this helps

I've tried entering incognito mode, and some variations of my code from things that I saw online like adding a path, but it did not work.

Comment: Try to add expire or max-age

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Fetch API in frontend, make sure to include `credentials: 'include'` in your request.

```js
return fetch('http://localhost:4000/login', {
    method: 'POST',
    credentials: 'include',
    body: JSON.stringify({
        email: 'test@test.com',
        password: 'Test@123'
    })
})
```

If you do not specify `credentials: 'include'`, browser will neither save the received cookies nor include existing cookies in the request header.

More details [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).